# saving multiple models in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a form that I save three entites in this form.

```
public class NewAccountWrapperModel
{
    Person Student = new Person();
    Person Parent = new Person();
    Reports Reports = new Reports();

    public NewAccountWrapperModel(Person student, Person parent, Reports reports)
    {
        this.Student = student;
        this.Parent = parent;
        this.Reports = reports;
    }
}
```

I prepare a model like above. In my html page, I uses it like below:

```
@model RAM_Web.Models.NewAccountWrapperModel
<!DOCTYPE html>



<span class="field">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname2" class="longinput" />
   @Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.Student.Name)
</span>
```

I try to achive to Student model using d.Student.Name.
But it gives error.

```
 NewAccountWrapperModel' does not contain a definition for 'Student' and no extension   method 'Student'
```

like this. In Person model, there is Name field. I controlled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from:

```
Person Student = new Person();
Person Parent = new Person();
Reports Reports = new Reports();
```

to:

```
public Person Student { get; set; }
public Person Parent { get; set; }
public Reports Reports { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks so muck. it is my carelessness. I don't notive that.Thanks again.